# Android - What's the advantage of using vector drawables in the app supporting minimum API level 20 or lesser?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am using support library for vector drawables in my app as below and `minSdkVersion` is 16.

```
android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
}
```

As per the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#apk), it suggests two approaches to deliver the app on the play store.

If I go with first approach which says:
**Create one APK that includes both the vector drawables and the corresponding raster representations. This solution is the simplest to implement.**

Does it have any advantage? As it includes both vector drawables and raster representation. Is it not increasing the apk size?

Comment: First of, **SVG != VectorDrawable** (VectorDrawables use a **limited subset** of SVG directives). Which is why I removed the `svg` tag. Second, the main advantage in using vector graphics over bitmap graphics is that the former is **scalable** without aliasing. Meaning that you don't need to provide different bitmaps for each screen density.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most importantly: **Test it**.

Get an emulator for at least your target sdk and min sdk and see if the app crashed or not, because with Vector Drawables and Support library there are *some* pitfalls.

#### Why use Vectors?

They can be scaled.

Whether you draw the drawable with the intended 24dp or scale it up to 100dp, it always looks fine. If you try the same thing with a bitmap, not so much.

Another thing is that they will drastically reduce your apk size, since they are in most  cases smaller than rasterized images.

The drawback is that they might take longer to draw, etc since there's more of parsing and drawing going on than just using a bitmap. This should although be neglectable if you keep your vectors simple.

Also read about [using vector drawables with the support library.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution)

#### Why *not* use vectors?

Other than the (possible) performance impact mentioned above, you might have to fix a few things like vectors within layer-list drawables and such, as support for those can be enabled but it is not recommended. Also it will not work for things like the window background on lower API versions, so if you do a splash screen by using the window background you might still want to use bitmaps only.

---

I personally use Vector Drawables wherever possible. It is especially useful if you want to modify colors or fix some stuff, as you can just modify the xml, and you don't have to get a new graphic export.

Comment: So I don't have much advantage as my app has min API level lesser than 20, unless I go for two apk approach to deliver the app on play store?

Comment: @Amit By using svgs you have great advantages and there is no need for a split apk. There is great svg support from the support library, just make sure to test it. Where did I lose you?

Comment: Sorry if I missed something but when I use single apk approach,  the support library generates both vector drawables and raster images(which are pngs). Is it not going to inflate apk size further? If it doesn't inflate the size as it would be by adding .PNGs for multiple densities then I am all for using vector drawable. Just need a clarification here.

Comment: @Amit You turn the generation of raster images **off** by adding `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` and the support library will be used to display them (at runtime, as vectors), see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution

Comment: Why android doesn't have complete support of the vectors?